# Android studio: no executable code found in line X

Tags: java, android, android-studio, tcp

So I have been developing a very simple TCP server/client application, but the problem is in almost every line I get android studio error in debug saying no executable code found in line X, after searching on the Internet I tried almost all the solutions with no hope so can you help me figure this out,

server class:

```java
package com.ziadbaaraka.gamedraft;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Message;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;

import static com.ziadbaaraka.gamedraft.hostActivity.serverHandler;

public class ServerConnectionThread extends Thread {

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    ServerConnectionThread ( ) { }

    @Override

    public void run ( ) {
        if ( serverSocket == null ) {
            int SERVER_PORT = 65000;
            Socket socket = null;
            try {
                while ( true ) {
                    serverSocket = new ServerSocket ( SERVER_PORT );

                    serverSocket.setReuseAddress ( true );
                    socket = serverSocket.accept ( );


                }
            } catch ( IOException e ) {

                e.printStackTrace ( );
            }

            String IpAddress2 = null;
            IpAddress2 = "192.168.1.4";

            String state = "Connected";
            Message msg = serverHandler.obtainMessage ( );
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle ( );

            bundle.putString ( "state" , state );
            bundle.putString ( "IP" , IpAddress2 );
            msg.setData ( bundle );
            serverHandler.sendMessage ( msg );
            UpdateServerThread updateThread = new UpdateServerThread ( socket );
            updateThread.run ( );
        }
    }
}
```

Like in `@Override` and try lines how can I even get such an error for a line like that.